# How do I select a '<td>' and navigate to url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am using jquery to pull football data from an api as follows

```
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
url: "http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/teams",
processData: true,
//idLength: url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) - 1,
//id: url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1, idLength),
success: function (data, status) {
    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(data.teams, function (key, item) {
        var id = item._links.self.href;
        var indexOfLastBackSlash = id.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        id = id.substring(indexOfLastBackSlash);
        //$('<option>', { text: item.TeamName, id: item.ID }).appendTo('#lstTeams');
        trHTML += '<tr class="info"><td>' + item.name +
                  '</td><td>' + item.code +
                  '</td><td>' + item.shortName +
                  '</td><td>' + item.squadMarketValue +
                  '</td><td>' + item.crestURL +
                  '</td><td>' + id +
                  '</td></tr>';
```

I want to be able to select a 'td' and navigate to another url like "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/322/fixtures" for the team with id of 322. How can I do so?

Comment: Can you please rephrase it? What do you mean by select a `td`?

Comment: Table will be populated with football team data. Using the click function select one and navigate to the url I provided using their id.

Comment: Where is your click function? Is it on an anchor? Please share more code or create a fiddle.

Comment: That is what I am wondering.. How can I select one of the td elements and navigate to a new page carrying the id? Or is it easier to do it on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `function` which will do same `ajax request` but this time for single record. On your target's `click event` you need to call that function passing the `id` you need to fetch records for. One way of doing this is to set a `data attribute` to your target container.

Below is the sample code performing similar functionality.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(Data) {
        $.each(Data, function (key, data) {
        var id = data.id;
        var title = data.title;
        $('.tableAllRecords').append('<tr><td><a href=# class=mylink data-id='+id+'>'+id+'</a></td><td>'+title+'</td></tr>');
      });
    });
});

function fetchSingle(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(data) {
        var id = data.id;
        var title = data.title;
        var body = data.body;
        $('.tableSingleRecord').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+title+'</td><td>'+body+'</td></tr>');
    }); 
}

$(document).on('click', '.mylink', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    fetchSingle(id);
    e.preventDefault(); // disabling anchor's default [redirect] behaviour
});
```

Here is the link to fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2h54vu7h/

If you need to display records on a new page, you simply have to pass `id` into your `url` and on next page you have make an ajax request getting the `id` variable from `url`.

Example: `'<a href=somepage.html?id='+id+'>View Details</a>';`